# What is the difference between screen_class, firebase_screen, and screen_id in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Between this: 
[screen_class example from GA's sample project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vzA9.png)

And this: 
[firebase_screen example from GA's sample project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLu8c.png)

And this: [screen_id example from GA's sample project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zET7.png)

What are use cases for each of them? Is firebase_screen the same as screen_class (i.e. screen name), but overrides it? 
I can't find any documentation for this except [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews), which doesn't make it clear, feel free to share what you've found and where. Thanks!

Comment: Got any answer about what's the difference b/w `firebase_screen` and `firebase_screen_class`?